# MergeSort in C using recursion

Tags: c, mergesort

I tried implementing the merge sort algorithm in C, but the array does not get sorted properly and some elements are lost, why is this the case? Below is the code that I have written:

`si` is the starting index, `ei` is the ending index.
I divided my array into 2 sub-arrays from `si` to `mid` and `mid+1` to `ei`. Then I used `mergeSort` function on both of these. I only ran the `mergeSort` till `si < ei`. And then I wrote a code to merge these two sorted array. My code gives the wrong output, but I cannot understand which part of the code is giving me the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei);
void merge(int arr[], int si, int mid, int ei);

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1 };
    mergeSort(arr, 0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei) {
    if (si < ei) {
        int mid = (si + ei) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, si, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ei);
        
        merge(arr, si, mid, ei);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int si, int mid, int ei) {
    int n1 = mid - si + 1, n2 = ei - mid;
    int A[n1], B[n2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        A[i] = arr[si + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        B[j] = arr[mid + j + 1];
    }
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
            arr[k++] = A[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = B[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k++] = A[i++];
    }
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k++] = B[j++];
    }
}
```

Comment: What sample array are you using? What result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the function `merge`: you initialize `k` to `0`, but it should be initialized to `si` so the merged data gets stored at the proper place in the array.  Just replace the definition with

```
   int i = 0, j = 0, k = si;
```

Note also these remarks:

- computing `mid` as `int mid = (si + ei) / 2;` is a classic bug: `si + ei` may overflow for large arrays and cause undefined behavior. You should write:

  ```
    int mid = si + (ei - si) / 2;
  ```
- it is not required to save the contents of the right half because these elements will not be overwritten before they are copied to their final place.
- copying the remaining elements from `B` is redundant as these elements are already in the proper place.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei);
void merge(int arr[], int si, int mid, int ei);

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1 };
    mergeSort(arr, 0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei) {
    if (si < ei) {
        int mid = si + (ei - si) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, si, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ei);
        merge(arr, si, mid, ei);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int si, int mid, int ei) {
    int n1 = mid - si + 1;
    int A[n1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        A[i] = arr[si + i];
    }

    int i = 0, j = mid + 1, k = si;
    while (i < n1 && j <= ei) {
        if (A[i] <= arr[j]) {
            arr[k++] = A[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k++] = A[i++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the error. Did we need to set k = si for the sub array that is formed on the right side? If so it makes a lot of sense as to why my code did not work before.